# Modifying .htaccess file for use with CodeIgniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter

CodeIgniter library is uploaded on `public_html/ci/` folder. I have already set the default controller inside `application/config/routes.php` as my default controller.

Now I want to update `.htaccess` file to match calls on *mysite.com* to `mysite.com/ci/index` controller or *mysite.com/about* to match `mysite.com/ci/about` controller, that pattern would use.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your .htaccess. Place .htaccess file under public_html/ci/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: no, I think you misunderstood me. I need to set rules on my public_html/